# Sketchfab api data with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby. I am trying to upload a .STL file to Sketchfab using the code that they have provided on Sketchfab website.

https://gist.github.com/sbouafif/3736968#file-sketchfab-api-rb

I have installed the required gems including - gem install ruby-multipart-post

When I run:

```
bundle install 
rake db:migrate
```

I get an error saying:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such a file -- ruby-multipart-post
```

I have never had this issue when installing gems.

Any help would be great.

I am using Ruby 1.9.3.

Thanks

Comment: gem install ruby-multipart-post

Answer (score 0):

You don't install `ruby-multipart-post` gem as recommended in [this](https://gist.github.com/sbouafif/3736968#file-sketchfab-api-rb-L9) line of script. Open terminal and install it use command:

```
gem install ruby-multipart-post
```